# Is there a visual in debug I can see the difference of using Dispose method on observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Given:
.Net 6 console application
Visual Studio 2022

Is there a visual when debugging that I can see the difference of disposing the observable vs forgetting to dispose of it?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/bNFwoQ

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace ObserverPatternPractice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Step 1 Create the observable.
            var observable = Observable.Range(5, 8);

            //Step 2 Subscribe to the observable.
            var subscription = observable.Subscribe(new Observer());

            //Step 3 Provide implementation for OnNext even.

            //Step 4 Dispose of the subscription when you 
            //do not want to listen anymore.
            subscription.Dispose();
        }
    }

    class Observer : IObserver<int>
    {
        public void OnCompleted()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stream completed signal");
        }

        public void OnError(Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error signal event");
        }

        public void OnNext(int value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"OnNext value is {value}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that a class's Dispose method is just that, it's code that the class author has written. It may release a native Handle, it may close a database collection, or it may revert the system cursor style back to normal (or, it may just do nothing; I've written empty Dispose methods before). Unless you know a sude-effect to look for, you won't be able to tell

Answer (score 1):

Try using this extension method:

```
public static IObservable<T> OnUnsubscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action unsubscribe) =>
    Observable
        .Create<T>(o =>
            new CompositeDisposable(
                source.Subscribe(o),
                Disposable.Create(unsubscribe)));
```

And change your observable to this:

```
var observable = Observable.Range(5, 8).OnUnsubscribe(() => Console.WriteLine("Disposed"));
```

Then your code produces:

```
OnNext value is 5
OnNext value is 6
OnNext value is 7
OnNext value is 8
OnNext value is 9
OnNext value is 10
OnNext value is 11
OnNext value is 12
Stream completed signal
Disposed
```